# How to sort mmm-yyyy date format in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

I have column its format is `mmmm-yyyy`  for a  eg. 'March-2013' 
How to sort  that column by `date` order....

I have tried with `ORDER by desc`

but its is sorting by Alphabetically... please help me

Comment: And you do not store the day ?

Comment: your column should be of type of `DATETIME` to use `order by` correctly, use `date_format` to get the desired output

Answer (score 4):

You can use [`str_to_date`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_str-to-date) to convert the string to a date:

```
SELECT   *
FROM     my_table
ORDER BY STR_TO_DATE(my_field, '%M-%Y') DESC
```

Answer (score 3):

If you are using aggregation, you can do something like:

```
order by min(col) desc
```

If not, you can convert to a date:

```
order by str_to_date(concat('01-', col), '%d-%M-%Y')
```

Strictly speaking you don't need the `01`, but I'm uncomfortable with MySQL's incomplete dates.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT * FROM articles ORDER BY time DESC
```

Comment: Include brief about the solution while suggesting code!